# When a theorem is the first thing in a list, prevent extra space

Tags: formatting, lists, theorems

I have an "indented" environment in my documents, which I create like this

```
\def\changemargin#1#2{
\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}
\item[]
} 
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist
```

Then if the first thing in the `changemargin` environment is a theorem, it will add an extra vertical space that shouldn't be there. How can I prevent this?

Examine

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist

\newtheorem*{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}

The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain.
The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain.
\begin{theorem}
This theorem has the correct spacing, because it's outside the changemargin environment.
\end{theorem}
The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain. The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain.

\begin{changemargin}{2cm}{2cm}
\begin{theorem} 
This theorem has the wrong spacing, becuase it is the first thing in the change margin environment.
\end{theorem}
\end{changemargin}
The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain. The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain.
\begin{changemargin}{2cm}{2cm}
The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain.
\begin{theorem}
This theorem has the correct spacing, because it is not the first thing in the changemargin environment.
\end{theorem}
\end{changemargin}
The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain. The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain.
\end{document}
```

[image]

One fix would be to create a macro for a theorem only to be used when it is the first thing in a changemargin environment. I'm wondering if there is anything better. Alternately, perhaps you could suggest a better way to change margins temporarily (not using `list`, I suppose) that wouldn't cause this problem.

**Update:** I am having trouble with the suggested answer below. A missing item error is being thrown to the following code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentEnvironment{changemargin}{O{3cm}D<>{3cm}}%
    {\list{}{\leftmargin=#1\rightmargin=#1}\item\@inlabelfalse\@newlistfalse}
    {\endlist}
\makeatother 

\newtheorem*{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{changemargin}[0.9cm]<0.5cm>
The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain.
\end{changemargin}
\begin{theorem}
The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With `ntheorem`   you can create indented theorems, so you might begin the indented environment *after* the theorem.

Comment: @Bernard It appears to only increase the left margin, not the right margin. Is that right?

Comment: No. It is not really explained in the doc , but you also can change the right margin with `\theoremrightindent some value` (see lines 582-584 of the code, p.55 of the doc)

Comment: @Bernard That is helpful. To switch to `ntheorem`, I'd have to rewrite the definition of my theorem environment into the new syntax of ntheorem. Do you find ntheorem is worth the effort?

Comment: In my opinion it has an easier syntax than amsthm. Some  problems have been reported in a few special cases, but I never met them.  Its main advantage is its automatic placement of (customisable) end-of-proof symbol, even when the proof ends  up in a displayed equation, and its ease of customisation. Finally, it can be used with `thmtools`.

Comment: Do you need the list and item stuff? This seems to be a rather cumbersome way of indentation.

Comment: @bort Can you suggests a better "indented" environment? It would be nice if it had the same spacing. Like `quote`.

Comment: @cfr Apologies. Should work now.

Comment: @Bort Perhaps there is a better way but if you look at the definitions of the "standard" indentation environments such as `quote`, `verse`, `description`, `enumerate`, `...`, you will find that they are all defined in a similar way using `\list`

Comment: I can’t understand why you have placed another bounty on this question and exactly what you are expecting from possible additional answers: it seems to me that @Andrew’s answer, albeit based on a non thoroughly correct analysis, works reasonably well in all significant contexts.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I placed the bounty when I realized Andrew's first answer was incomplete (after prematurely awarding him the bounty). User cfr made a crucial fix, and I want him to capture the second bounty, but I can't award it yet. Then Andrew fixed his answer, too.

Comment: Eric, not sure how the bonus rules work but if you can you should shift  it to Gustavo Mezzetti.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two working answers has already been given to this questions; nonetheless, both answers fail to provide a detailed explanation of what is actually going on, and their authors plainly admit that their understanding of why those answers work is not perfect.  Indeed, it is difficult—even for me—to tell whether or not the aforementiond solutions are guaranteed to work under any reasonable circumstance.

I decided to write this answer after getting a headache in the effort of sorting this out, essentially because it was clearly impossible to make it fit even in more than one comment.  I hope that I’ll be able to shed some light on the matter, but please note that my understanding is not yet perfect too.

“Theorem-like” environments defined by means of the default facilities
provided by the LaTeX kernel interact with lists in a perfectly correct way, as the following example shows:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

% \usepackage{amsthm}

\newenvironment*{changemargins}[2]{%
    \list{}{%
        \setlength\leftmargin {#1}%
        \setlength\rightmargin{#2}%
    }\item\relax
}{\endlist}

\newtheorem{thrm}{Theorem}



\begin{document}

``Theorem-like'' environments defined by means of the default facilities
provided by the \LaTeX\ kernel interact correctly with lists.

A theorem at the outer level:

\begin{thrm}
    The ducks in dutch quack quaveringly on the docks.
\end{thrm}

Now inside a list: first making up an item by itself\ldots
\begin{enumerate}
    \item
        \begin{thrm}
            The ducks in dutch quack quaveringly on the docks.
        \end{thrm}

    \item
        \ldots and then after some text.
        \begin{thrm}
            The ducks in dutch quack quaveringly on the docks.
        \end{thrm}

    \item
        A third item follows.
\end{enumerate}

In the same way, their behavior when used by themselves inside a
\texttt{changemargins} environment is absolutely normal:

\begin{changemargins}{2cm}{2cm}
    \begin{thrm}
        The ducks in dutch quack quaveringly on the docks.
    \end{thrm}
\end{changemargins}

Another example, in which the ``theorem-like'' environment follows some text:

\begin{changemargins}{2cm}{2cm}
    Some text, what suffices to get to the right margin\ldots\space
    Well, perhaps just a little more.
    \begin{thrm}
        The ducks in dutch quack quaveringly on the docks.
    \end{thrm}
\end{changemargins}

Uncommenting
\begin{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\end{verbatim}
will break all the above examples, so it looks like the
\textsf{amsthm} package is the real culprit!

\end{document}
```

If you uncomment the `\usepackage{amsthm}` declaration, you will see that the “culprit” is actually this package.  Indeed, the machinery of the various switches like `\if@newlist`, `\if@inlabel`, and so on, relies on the assumption that `list`-type environments are nested according to the following pattern:

```
\begin{list}{...}{...}
    \item
        \begin{list}{...}{...}
            \item
                Text
```

In other words, every `list`-type environment (including “`trivlist`-type” ones!) should directly enclose an `\item` command, or something equivalent, *before any other actual contents*, lest a ”missing `\item`” error be returned.  But we can see (file `amsthm.sty`, lines 186–199) that the `amsthm` package, after having issued (line 123) a `\trivlist`, does not directly use an `\item` command, as the corresponding facility provided by the LaTeX kernel does, but rather “something equivalent”, which, though, does not honor the `\if@noparitem` switch.

The following example patches the relevant macro in the `amsthm` package, to make “theorem-like” environments behave as expected inside lists too.  I prefer not to use the `\patchcmd` facility from the `etoolbox` package, both because the patch is a bit complex and for reasons of readability; bold guys are of course free to do differently.

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter

\def\deferred@thm@head#1{%
  \if@noparlist
    \@donoparitem
  \else
    \if@inlabel \indent \par \fi % eject a section head if one is pending
    \if@nobreak
      \adjust@parskip@nobreak
    \else
      \addpenalty\@beginparpenalty
      \addvspace\@topsep
      \addvspace{-\parskip}%
    \fi
    \global\@inlabeltrue
  \fi
  \everypar\dth@everypar
  \global\sbox\@labels{\unhbox\@labels\normalfont#1}%
  \ignorespaces
}

\makeatother

\newenvironment*{changemargins}[2]{%
    \list{}{%
        \setlength\leftmargin {#1}%
        \setlength\rightmargin{#2}%
    }\item\relax
}{\endlist}

\newtheorem{thrm}{Theorem}



\begin{document}

``Theorem-like'' environments defined by means of the default facilities
provided by the \LaTeX\ kernel interact correctly with lists.

A theorem at the outer level:

\begin{thrm}
    The ducks in dutch quack quaveringly on the docks.
\end{thrm}

Now inside a list: first making up an item by itself\ldots
\begin{enumerate}
    \item
        \begin{thrm}
            The ducks in dutch quack quaveringly on the docks.
        \end{thrm}

    \item
        \ldots and then after some text.
        \begin{thrm}
            The ducks in dutch quack quaveringly on the docks.
        \end{thrm}

    \item
        A third item follows.
\end{enumerate}

In the same way, their behavior when used by themselves inside a
\texttt{changemargins} environment is absolutely normal:

\begin{changemargins}{2cm}{2cm}
    \begin{thrm}
        The ducks in dutch quack quaveringly on the docks.
    \end{thrm}
\end{changemargins}

Another example, in which the ``theorem-like'' environment follows some text:

\begin{changemargins}{2cm}{2cm}
    Some text, what suffices to get to the right margin\ldots\space
    Well, perhaps just a little more.
    \begin{thrm}
        The ducks in dutch quack quaveringly on the docks.
    \end{thrm}
\end{changemargins}

\end{document}
```

Please note that, in order to keep the example simple, I’ve not considered the `xparse` syntax: that is an “orthogonal” feature.

This patch has the following advantages over the other ones:

- I know precisely why it works `;-)` ;
- it works with all types of list environments.

Nevertheless, this does not mean that I am completely sure that it doesn’t break anything; indeed, the comment on line 187 of `amsthm.sty` suggests that it could.  For this reason, I also propose another solution that keeps the patch to the `amsthm` macro local to the `changemargins` environment:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\PatchAmsThmMacros{%
  \def\deferred@thm@head##1{%
    \if@noparlist
      \@donoparitem
    \else
      \if@inlabel \indent \par \fi % eject a section head if one is pending
      \if@nobreak
        \adjust@parskip@nobreak
      \else
        \addpenalty\@beginparpenalty
        \addvspace\@topsep
        \addvspace{-\parskip}%
      \fi
      \global\@inlabeltrue
    \fi
    \everypar\dth@everypar
    \global\sbox\@labels{\unhbox\@labels\normalfont##1}%
    \ignorespaces
  }%
}

\makeatother

\newenvironment*{changemargins}[2]{%
    \list{}{%
        \setlength\leftmargin {#1}%
        \setlength\rightmargin{#2}%
    }%
    \PatchAmsThmMacros
    \item\relax
}{\endlist}

\newtheorem{thrm}{Theorem}



\begin{document}

``Theorem-like'' environments defined by means of the default facilities
provided by the \LaTeX\ kernel interact correctly with lists.

A theorem at the outer level:

\begin{thrm}
    The ducks in dutch quack quaveringly on the docks.
\end{thrm}

Now inside a list: first making up an item by itself\ldots
\begin{enumerate}
    \item
        \begin{thrm}
            The ducks in dutch quack quaveringly on the docks.
        \end{thrm}

    \item
        \ldots and then after some text.
        \begin{thrm}
            The ducks in dutch quack quaveringly on the docks.
        \end{thrm}

    \item
        A third item follows.
\end{enumerate}

In the same way, their behavior when used by themselves inside a
\texttt{changemargins} environment is absolutely normal:

\begin{changemargins}{2cm}{2cm}
    \begin{thrm}
        The ducks in dutch quack quaveringly on the docks.
    \end{thrm}
\end{changemargins}

Another example, in which the ``theorem-like'' environment follows some text:

\begin{changemargins}{2cm}{2cm}
    Some text, what suffices to get to the right margin\ldots\space
    Well, perhaps just a little more.
    \begin{thrm}
        The ducks in dutch quack quaveringly on the docks.
    \end{thrm}
\end{changemargins}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, this makes the patch work with the `changemargins` environment, but not with `enumerate`.

Comment: Thank you very much — this fixed an outstanding problem for my users.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT (rewrite and simplification of code)**

I delved back into the definition of theorem-like environments and I think that I found what causes the problem when trying to use `\list` to do this. Namely, it is lines 4559-4566 from latex.ltx which form part of the definition of `\trivlist`:

```
\if@inlabel
  \@noparitemtrue
  \@noparlisttrue
\else
  \if@newlist \@noitemerr \fi
  \@noparlistfalse
  \@topsep \@topsepadd
\fi
```

What is happening is that `\list` sets `\@inlabeltrue` and, in turn, this leads to extra space being added at the top of any environment that uses `\trivlist`, of which there are many. To stop this happening we just need to disable this. Once this is done the MWE in the question produces:

[image]

Here is the new code, which is quite a bit simpler than my first attempt:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[margin=16mm,showframe]{geometry}% to show the margins

\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentEnvironment{changemargin}{O{3cm}D<>{3cm}}%
    {\list{}{\leftmargin=#1\rightmargin=#2}\item%
     \bgroup\@inlabelfalse\@newlistfalse}% change flags only in a group
    {\egroup\endlist}
\makeatother

\newtheorem*{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

  The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain.
  The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain.
  \begin{theorem}
    This theorem has the correct spacing, because it's outside the changemargin environment.
  \end{theorem}
  The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain. The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain.

  \begin{changemargin}[2cm]<2cm>
    \begin{theorem}
      This theorem has the right spacing and it is the first thing in the change margin environment.
    \end{theorem}
    \end{changemargin}
    The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain. The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain.
    \begin{changemargin}[2cm]<2cm>
      The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain.
    \begin{theorem}
    This theorem has the correct spacing, because it is not the first thing in the changemargin environment.
    \end{theorem}
  \end{changemargin}
  The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain. The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain.

\end{document}
```

The `\@newlistfalse` is necessary because without latex gives an error, saying that there is a missing `\item`. As far as I can see there are no additional side-effects of adding the lines `\@inlabelfalse\@newlistfalse` as they will simply stop extra space being added to *any* environment that uses `\trivlist`. Of course, I may have missed something!

The only other comment worth making is that I have changed the OP's `\changemargin` macro into an enviroment by using `\NewDocumentEnvironment` from [xparse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse). The environment has two optional arguments, which can be used independently, for setting the margins in the `changemargin` environment. For example,

```
  \begin{changemargin}[2cm]<4cm>
    Here is the correct spacing.
  \end{changemargin}
```

sets the left-hand margin to `2cm` and the right-hand margin to `4cm`. Both margins default to `3mm`.

Comment: @EricAuld I have replaced my hack with a solution. I will delete my other comments here as they are no longer relevant.

Comment: There's a "missing item" error being thrown. Check out the code in the question. Perhaps you can help me figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @EricAuld What is happening in your example is that the `@inlabel` flag is wrong for the next theorem environment when it's not inside a `changemargin` environment. This was definitely a mistake in my code as the `changemargin` environment should not change the "state" of external environments. I think that the best way to fix is to make these changes "local" by putting them inside a group. I have updated my answer so that it does this.

Comment: I’m afraid your analysis is not correct: try `\begin{enumerate}\item \begin{trivlist}\item Foo.\item Bar.\end{trivlist} \end{enumerate}`, and you’ll see that it is handled correctly.  The point is that the “theorem-like” environments defined by the `amsthm` package, albeit implemented through a `trvilist` environment, do not honor `\@noparitemtrue` (see `amsthm.sty`, lines 186–199).

Answer (score 2):

**Note: I don't know what I'm doing.**

## *Caveat emptor ...*

I added the additions just to check I'd not broken the spacing inadvertently. The code change is from `latex.ltx`. Also, I corrected the use of `#1` in place of `#2`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentEnvironment{changemargin} {O{3cm}D<>{3cm}}
{%
  \list{}{\leftmargin=#1\rightmargin=#2}\item
  \if@inlabel\global\@inlabelfalse\fi
  \@newlistfalse
}{%
  \endlist
}
\makeatother

\newtheorem*{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{changemargin}[0.9cm]<0.5cm>
  The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain.
  \begin{theorem}
    The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain.
  \end{theorem}
\end{changemargin}
The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain.
\begin{theorem}
  The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image: lots of rain on Spain's plain]

Comment: Using `\global` might have unintended effects with nesting...but perhaps not. What is going wrong with the OP's example is that the flags are screwed up for the next theorem environment, which is outside the `changemargin` environment. I'll update my solution with what is probably a safer solution... Thanks for fixing my `#2`:)

Comment: @Andrew You are probably right. I just looked at similar cases in `latex.ltx` to see what they did when using `\if@inlabel` etc. I did check that the flag is set globally to false by the format.